# Using Neo4j Core Java API and terminal console together

Tags: java, database, neo4j, graph-databases

I am writing an application that collects huge amount of data and store it in Neo4j. For this I'm using Java code.

In order to quickly analyze the data I want to use terminal Neo4j server to connect to the same database and then use Neo4j console to query on it using Cypher.

This seems to be a lot of hassle. I have already changed, neo4j-server.properties to connect the directory where my java code is collecting the data. And also changed the flag allow_store_upgrade=true in neo4j.properties.

However, I am still facing issues because of locks.

Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `neo4j-shell-<version>.jar` on your classpath and set a `remote_shell_enabled='true'` as config option while initializing your embedded instance.

I've written up a blog post on this some time ago: http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2014/01/using-remote-shell-combined-with-neo4j-embedded/